# Show module on specific page like /business?task=confirmapp

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am trying to make a sort of bootstrap wizard with a progress bar. It is basically a series of three custom HTML modules with Step 1, Step 2 and Step 3.

- The "Step 1" module is shown on a page called www.mywebsite.com/**pricing**
- The "Step 2" module is shown on a page called www.mywebsite.com/**business**
- The final "Step 3" module is shown on a page inside the scheduling component called www.mywebsite.com/**business?task=confirmapp**

At the moment I can't get two separate modules to show on the /business and /business?task=confirmapp pages.

The module I want to display on the page with the link **business?task=confirmapp** (querystring) is called "Wizard 3" and I want to display it in a position called "masthead" on the specific page.

Is there a way to do this without too much coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Welcome to joomla's "each page is tied to menu" thing. Your problem can be solved by taking following steps

**What you need:** an `Itemid` so that you can identify a page in back-end.

**What you're going to do**

- Create a hidden menu, a menu that isn't displayed anywhere on the website. Sole purpose of this menu is to produce valid `Itemid`s.
- Create a new menu item with a relevant name, e.g., "BS Wizard Final Step"
- Assign desired modules to this menu item
- Note this menu items `Itemid`
- Use this `Itemid` in query string for your last step, e.g, `business?task=confirmapp&Itemid=99`

This *should* solve the issue.

Comment: Hi there Ejaz! I want to truely thank you for such a well thought out answer, this is certainly a very good way of solving thew issue and I have learned something new about joomla through it... I managed to solve the issue using the advanced module manager extension and setting the module to only display on the specific link and also setting the other modules to be excluded on the specific querystring link. It worked too, so either way thanks for your help!

Comment: Ejaz, you now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.